# Microsoft.Data.SqlClient NuGet is needed in some projects but others you can do using Microsoft.Data.SqlClient without the NuGet

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-6.0, microsoft-data-sqlclient

In some projects I need to add NuGet package Microsoft.Data.SqlClient to the project before I can do

```
using Microsoft.Data.SqlClient
```

In other projects, I can do that without explicitly adding the NuGet package.
The examples below are both .NET 6.0 projects (same for .NET 5).

**Referenced directly:**
[image: Nuget Microsoft.Data.SqlClient required]

**Not referenced directly:**
[image: Nuget Microsoft.Data.SqlClient not required]

I am wondering how this works.
Is the package referenced indirectly somehow?

Comment: Doh, I actually see `AspNetCore.HealthChecks.SqlServer` has dependency on `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient`

Comment: No, you can't ignore the NuGet package. `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient` is a new driver, only available as a NuGet package. It was never included in the .NET SDK and not meant to be. That's why the name changed from `System.Data.SqlClient` to `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient`. The package has to be referenced either directly or indirectly.

Comment: BTW Microsoft.Data.SqlClient was released recently so you probably shouldn't depend on the minimum version referenced by another package.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - well, it shows that you don't have to add the NuGet yourself. It can be indirectly referenced via another NuGet. In my case, Microsoft.Data.SqlClient is referenced by AspNetCore.HealthChecks.SqlServer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`AspNetCore.HealthChecks.SqlServer`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AspNetCore.HealthChecks.SqlServer) depends on `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient`:

- .NETStandard 2.0

  - Microsoft.Data.SqlClient (>= 2.1.2)
  - Microsoft.Extensions.Diagnostics.HealthChecks (>= 5.0.1)
- net5.0

  - Microsoft.Data.SqlClient (>= 2.1.2)
  - Microsoft.Extensions.Diagnostics.HealthChecks (>= 5.0.1)

so as transitive dependency `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient` becomes available for you also.